# Why JUnit test may fail even when no changes are made to database

Tags: java, spring, junit, dbunit

So I'm working now with some Java and Junit tests. I'm also using DbUnit for convinient database setup and teardown. I've got massive database with over 40 tables.

To simplify I'm trying to teardown my database using

```
[...]
@DatabaseTeardown("classpath:/emptyDb.xml")
public MyClassTest
```

my `emptyDb.xml` includes empty row for each table in the database like:

```
<dataset>
    <database.table1 />
    <database.table2 />
    ...
    <database.tableN />
</dataset>
```

I've also created similar file for the data init, just rows aren't empty. Let's call it `initDb.xml` and I've encountered very strange behaviour, my test metod fails even, through it shouldn't. My test case below:

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:/initDb.xml")
@ExpectedDatabase("classpath/initDb.xml") // yes I'm using the same file on purpose
public void myTest()
{} // empty method body is part of a test here
```

And from what I understand this simple test should always succeed, but the case is, it fails with error trace looking like this:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: table count expected:<4[1]> but was:<4[8]>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.createFailure(DefaultFailureHandler.java:105)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:237)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:205)
    at org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(Assertion.java:104)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.DefaultDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(DefaultDatabaseAssertion.java:33)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:115)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:67)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:406)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:90)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Any suggestions what may cause such behaviour? I was searching for solutions, and it seems definitely something is wrong with database tables but i cannot find out what.

---

Update
Problem apears only for strict assertion mode

Comment: Are there *system* tables alongside your own tables?

Comment: @BrianAgnew from what I know it's a Postgres database so they may be there. Also i know that database is using three schemas if it's important too.